# Convert HANA XSC app into Mobile app?

Tags: cordova, sapui5, hybrid-mobile-app, hana, hana-xs

Is it possible to convert HANA XSC that runs XSJS and OData services into a hybrid app?

Cordova framework converts UI5 apps into a hybrid app. But my concern is to convert app that uses HANA features.

Any help would be appreciated!
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You would not actually convert the `XSC` app into a native app like you would `UI5` but in this case, what you can do is build your `UI5` app to access and use the `XSODATA` service from the `XSC` app.

Then you would continue using `Cordova` for example to make the native app.

I actually run many `XSC` apps as "webapps" on my phone but have also done the `XSC` XSODATA service to iOS for example.